# Button for modal does nothing when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I created a button that references a modal but it doesn't open the modal at all. This area of code isn't my realm, SQL is. This code actually lives in an SQL procedure that is called when interacting with a website.

Thoughts?

```
--Remove package item, Modal Popup
    <div id="delete_btn_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class=modal-body>
                <h3><font color="red" align="center">Are you sure?</h3></font></br>
                <p>Deleting a package item will remove the entire package</br></br>
                    <button type="button" class="btnStyle" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
                    <button type="button" class="btnStyle" onclick=location.href="http://wowfestival.lajollaplayhouse.org/cart/precart.aspx?p=499">Delete Package</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

--button
        <button type="button" class="btnStyle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_btn_modal">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Are your Bootstrap Dependencies in place (jQuery + Bootstrap CSS/JS)?

Comment: Not sure, where would I find those? Some trouble I am having here is I don't have full access to the website or it's files. I am solely working in an SQL procedure that is called by the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have not added bootstrap javascript

Your code is perfect and fine

Check the bootply for your code. : http://www.bootply.com/zOa8UJ4Vfb

Also check you you have jQuery included as well .

If not use below cdn for quick test.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added the snippet of code you included and the button is now clickable and brings up the modal. However, I had this working a couple weeks ago without that code, not sure what could have changed? Also, it used to bring up a small box but now it just dims the entire screen. Any idea what's going on here?